# laravel schedule not working automatically

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5.1

I am using a godaddy host. I already set the cron job command in the host php /home/site/laravel/artisan schedule:run

But the problem its returning this error for everytime it runs:  [ErrorException]
  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Content-type: text/html

Also it runs if i use the same artisan command in the ssh

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the answer i had to use the command with the full path to the php like this: /usr/local/bin/php /home/mysitename/laravel/artisan schedule:run